# ionic 3 component Input() values "isn't a known property of" component used in lazy-loaded page

Tags: lazy-loading, ionic3, angular-components

I have an ionic page that is lazyloaded `page1` where I want to use a custom component generated by me.
So when I've generated the component and the CLI get me this:

```
components
  result
   result.html
   result.scss
   result.ts
components.module.ts
```

and **components.module.ts** contain:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ResultComponent } from './result/result';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ResultComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [ResultComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**result.ts**
//relevant code

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativePageTransitions, NativeTransitionOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';

@Component({
  selector: 'result',
  templateUrl: 'result.html'
})
export class ResultComponent {

@Input() toSlide:string;
@Input() isCorrectValue:boolean;
```

**page1.html**

```
<result [toSlide] = "link" [isCorrectValue]="result"></result>
```

**page1.module.ts**

```
import { ResultComponent } from './../../components/result/result';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page1Page } from './page1';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Page1Page,
    ResultComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Page1Page),
  ],
})
export class Page1PageModule {}
```

Error is:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'toSlide' since it isn't a known property of 'result'. ("   ][toSlide] = "link" [isCorrectValue]="result">"): ng:///Page1PageModule/Page1Page.html
>
> ...

If I remove the properties from result html code works well but it's useless.
I think is a minor issue but I can't get it to work.

Also I would like to make it work by importing the component in **app.module.ts** instead of in every page module

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you import ComponentModule? in app.module.ts?

Comment: @suraj I didn't import that anywhere - somehow my code works now if I import `ResultComponent` in `page1.module.ts` at `declarations` but it doesn't if I try to import it in `app.module.ts` at `declarations`

Comment: Try importing ComponentsModule in your pagemodule instead of declaring...

Comment: @suraj - it seems to work like this as well, don't know what happened cuz I've tried this variants before and it didn't work

Comment: only thing that it doesn't work is to include the result in `app.module.ts` it gives me the printed error

Comment: anyway I've realized that it's a bad approach what I'm doing and now I'm using a page not a component for result

Comment: thanks for your time pal

Comment: you have already declared in ComponentsModule.. you dont have to declare again. just import the module when you need it

Comment: i think that the difference was that after I posted here I did this: `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev` and recreated the component